# Boot Camp Assistant can't be used since disk is not journaled even though it is

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

I'm trying to install Win7 onto my mid-2010 iMac using Bootcamp. After starting Bootcamp I click "Continue" and get this message:

> Boot Camp Assistant cannot be used.
>
> The disk is not journaled. You must enable journaling using Disk Utility before using the Boot Camp Assistant.

However when I Get Info on my HD, under "Format" it reads:

> Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

If my HD is journaled then why is Boot Camp stopping me from going along with the partitioning and then install of Win7?

System: iMac, 8 GB RAM, OS X 10.9.2, 3.6 GHz i5 CPU, 1 TB HDD

[image: Screenshot]