# Do I need to enable Journaling on a Mac Pro M2 SSD?

Tags: bootcamp, ssd, mac-pro, mojave

I am booting from an M2 SSD (PCI) on my Mac Pro 2012.
Running Mojave. I tried to run the Boot Camp Assistant but it doesn't run and I've seen solutions saying that you have to have Journaling enabled. If I'm using APFS, can I even enable Journaling in order to make Boot Camp work? Or if not, does that mean if you are using APFS you can't use boot camp assistant? There doesnt seem to be an option to enable Journaling on the drive so I dont want to try to force it in Terminal if its not even possible. Source of the pic: https://www.howtogeek.com/331042/whats-the-difference-between-apfs-macos-extended-hfs-and-exfat/

[image: https://www.howtogeek.com/331042/whats-the-difference-between-apfs-macos-extended-hfs-and-exfat/]

Comment: Journalling is a property of a file system that basically lets it keep track of what has been done. In a case of a crash, it's easier to restore. Notice, that there is no option for non-journaled HFS+. I'd recon there are problems with BootCamp on the Windows side, when using APFS. APFS uses a more modern approach (keyword "copy on write") instead of journaling.

Answer (score 1):

There’s basically zero downside for journaling the filesystem metadata and huge, huge upsides so even though you don’t need to do it, I recommend everyone does it as if they needed to. The only reason not to enable journaling is if you have some desire to test failure modes of a less robust filesystem.

As to the larger question, the boot camp info you read likely is wrong (please link to the exact article or advice if we can help be precise if it is outdated or correct).

What’s true is you can’t have APFS and boot camp. Pick either / or

- HFS with journal and the possibility to use boot camp
- APFS which journals always and no possibility to use boot camp that shares space with APFS

Now you can partition your drive to be part APFS and part HFS / bootcamp, so here is the boot camp FAQ for Mojave if you want to go ahead with that plan:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468

Comment: I put in more details in a separate answer which was too long for comments. Here's the same problem I was mentioning: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/bootcamp-no-longer-functional-with-cmp-5-1-w-mojave-update.2144072/ . And at the end of the day, if this ever does work, I tried downloading BootChamp to make the switching easier but i'm not sure its worth the hassle. Clearly it is worth a lot of hassle since I've spent so much time on it already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you are right, the [journaling thing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125841/boot-camp-assistant-cant-be-used-since-disk-is-not-journaled-even-though-it-is) was for a similar but different error. My error is this, my Mac does not support Boot Camp. Instead I switched to a different drive with Sierra installed and it let me into Boot Camp Assistant - it didnt work but it let me in. I explain the steps below.
[image: Boot Camp Assistant cannot be used]

I've close to given up, but so far I've managed to get the Bootcamp partition installed.

**My setup** has some "unsupported things" which has complicated things

- cMP 2012 5,1 (12 core) with RX580 which just replaced my HD5870 stock GPU.
- M2 SSD connected via PCI (with Mojave)
- 1TB SSD (with Sierra)
- 2TB HD  (also Sierra - I dont use this)

**Installing Boot Camp**

**My goal:** to install Bootcamp onto the 2TB drive.

**Things I've done so far**

- I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C52rH7LjdjQ) to which was helpful but I wasn't able to finish all the steps.
- I switched to my Sierra install on a regular SSD which let me load Boot Camp assistant (without the error above). It had problems however because Mac Pro 2012 can't boot to USB. So I saw some tips on how to edit the PLIST file (removed MacPro5,1 from the PreUSB something). That got me 1 step further but only Win7 could install. So I went back into the PLIST and removed my MacPro5,1 from a couple more lines and finally it would allow "Win7 or later" Yay!
- WIN10 ISO: Now I needed the Win10 ISO on a bootable USB (or so I thought). So I fought with the Win10 bootable disk maker which kept giving errors until I found a 3rd party tool to make the bootable USB with the ISO. It worked. Then I discovered that the Bootcamp assistant is going to erase the USB and install it's own. Boot Camp assistant errored out a couple times, I tried one last time, it worked! Yay.
- Partition: Bootcamp assistant allowed me to make a Win10 Partition on my 2tb HD. The computer restarted itself and then I got this fun error "No bootable device -- insert boot disk", below is a not my screen shot but a similar one found on google. I guess this is because the MacPro5,1 cannot boot to USB which is why they restrict it (which I hacked above to remove that restriction)
  [image]
- **Boot Camp Partition** Now I have an RX580 GPU so I can't see the boot screen selector. So I put in my stock video card so I can see and hold down the option menu and select the BootCamp partition, but... there IS NO BOOT CAMP Partition. I reboot to OSX and see the BootCamp partition but can't get to it. If I was able to manually select it as the boot drive, according to that video I linked above, I should be able to insert the USB and install Win10.
- STUCK: So here I am, I can't install Win10 on the Bootcamp partition because I can't manually select the BootCamp partition during the boot process. I just put my rX580 back in and gave up. I've only spent a good 15 hours troubleshooting all this over the course of a week. Complete waste of time but I know others have done it so I knew it was possible. So close I can smell it but I don't know how to proceed.